# Changing a select column makes a query slow

Tags: mysql

Two queries:

```
SELECT
  e.*,
  rb.auto_id
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN rb ON e.some_key=rb.some_key
WHERE
  e.something='xyzzy' AND e.something_else IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e.`timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 200
```

is blazing fast (0.01 seconds)

Changing rb.auto_id to rb.some_timestamp makes the query slow

```
SELECT
  e.*,
  rb.some_timestamp
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN rb ON e.some_key=rb.some_key
WHERE
  e.something='xyzzy' AND e.something_else IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e.`timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 200
```

It seems that my query should already have all of the data from RB, so why is this taking so long?  Also, the rb table has zero records right now.  This will grow, but why is there any performance hit here?

Both e.some_key and rb.some_key are indexed

Running `EXPLAIN` on the two queries shows two different execution plans:

Fast Query `EXPLAIN`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: e
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: event_col1_index,event_col2_index,event_col3_index,event_col1_col_4_index,event_col1_col3_index
          key: **timestamp_index**
      key_len: 6
          ref: NULL
         rows: **580**
     filtered: 9.01
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: id,id_index
          key: id
      key_len: 767
          ref: dbname.e.col_3
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: rb
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: rb_col_1,rb_col_1_index
          key: rb_col_1
      key_len: 1023
          ref: func
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Slow query `EXPLAIN`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: e
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: event_col1_index,event_col2_index,event_col3_index,event_col1_col_4_index,event_col1_col3_index
          key: **event_col1_index**
      key_len: 767
          ref: const
         rows: **146832**
     filtered: 26.17
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: id,id_index
          key: id
      key_len: 767
          ref: dbname.e.col_3
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: rb
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: rb_col_1,rb_col_1_index
          key: **NULL**
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec
```

Comment: Is `rb.auto_id` also indexed ? Also you should really avoid using `select *`.

Comment: auto_id is the auto increment key, it is indexed.  I'm not actually using e.*, but simplified the query for the sake of the question

Comment: MySQL optimizer can use indexing (which is generally in-memory due to InnoDB buffer) also to `select` the column data. That is why you have this performance variation.